# How to connect to Google cloud VPC from on-premise machine

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-vpn

I have a VPC called 'subnet-1' where I have 3 VM Instances and 1 SQL Instance (Postgresql to be precise). All of them with no Public IP, just Private IP. They are in a kubernetes cluster.

The requirement I have is to be able to connect to the VPC from my on-premise PC in order to use some SQLClient to connect to the PG and see the data, I have read about CloudVPN but don't know how to configure it to have what I want... does anyone of you ever done some configuration like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cloud VPN but that is a site-to-site VPN that requires supported routers and solid knowledge of routing, networking and VPNs.

[Using third-party VPNs with Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/interop-guides)

For small businesses or home based developers that only need to connect a few users to a VPC, use an open source product like OpenVPN. Google Marketplace offers a deployable configuration for your project with a click configuration. Simple and easy to deploy.

[Google Cloud Marketplace OpenVPN](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/openvpn-access-server-200800/openvpn-access-server)

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to Kubernetes Cluster from your on-premises networks you can use Cloud VPN. The configuration of Cloud VPN with the Cluster and On-Premise network is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cp-on-prem-routing).