# How to access GCP resource in private server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My application deployed to our private server and I want to use some service from GCP like Bucket and Secret manager.
Suppose my application deployed in internal server and my applicate use GCP services. Is it possible or we should deploy our app to GCP also. My application is in JSP.

How to do this. Which is best practice for this.

Comment: You can use [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access). As They can reach the external IP addresses of Google APIs and services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one option. You can use [**Cloud VPN**](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview), as it securely connects your peer network to your **Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)** network through an **IPsec VPN** connection. Follow this [GCP’s official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely) to set it up.

Another option is [**Google Cloud Hybrid Connectivity**](https://cloud.google.com/hybrid-connectivity) focused on **Cloud Interconnect** as it allows you to connect your infrastructure to **Google Cloud**. Visit the following link for the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/concepts/best-practices) and the [set up guide](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/interconnect/how-to/enabling-multiple-networks-access-same-attachment).

Finally, see the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65116248/how-to-connect-to-google-cloud-vpc-from-on-premise-machine) for more reference on your connection requirement.